# SSO implementation in two virtual host PHP

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I have two virtual hosts:

```
Ex. testproject1.net and
    testproject2.net
```

I created two simple login script there. I want to implement SSO implementation for it. Once user Authenticate with testproject1.net I want to set session for both virtual hosts (testproject1.net and testproject2.net). Means if I opened the testproject2.net it authenticate automatically by taking the session value.

Please help for dealing with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to set session for this?

Comment: The easiest way is to make both sites use the same session store. Of course it is not always that simple if the sites are already running and have users so sometimes you have to make cookies write for both domains, which is...troublesome.

Comment: If user authenticate with testproject1.net set the session for it and also for testproject2.net so that no need to authenticate again in testproject2.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here it goes. If you want, have another `Virtual Host` with `authproject.net`. And post the authentication information to the form there. Let it set in the session.

Now, once you give the credentials to the `authproject.net` domain and also where to go after auth, it posts the auth data to the respective destination.

#### Source of `testproject1.net/index.php`:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"]))
        die($_SESSION["user"]["name"] . " is logged in!");
    else
        die('<a href="auth.php">Login</a>');
?>
```

#### Source of `testproject1.net/auth.php`:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && !count($_POST))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }
    elseif (count($_POST))
        if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "letmein")
            $_SESSION["user"]["title"] = "Administrator"; # The session is set
        else
            showForm(); # Invalid Password
    else
        showForm(); # Log In Screen
?>

<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && !count($_POST))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }
    elseif (count($_POST))
        if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "letmein")
        {
            $_SESSION["user"]["title"] = "Administrator"; # The session is set
            if (isset($_GET["redirect"]))
            {
                # Start crappy implementation :P
                echo '<form method="post" action="', $_GET["redirect"], '/auth.php" id="authfrm"><input type="hidden" name="username" value="', $username, '"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="', $password, '"></form><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("authfrm").submit();</script>';
            }
            else
                header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else
            showForm(); # Invalid Password
    else
        showForm(); # Log In Screen
?>
```

#### The same to be carried out in all the sites. Hope you get it.

Comment: Can it possible to set same session for two domains using this?

Comment: If just two, go with instead of checking `authproject.net`, check in `testproject2.net` if the request was raised from `testproject1.net` and vice versa. You get it? I just said it would be tedious if its gonna be 100s of sites like our StackExchange. Where they have a common login `StackExchange.com`, which logs you into `stackoverflow.com`, `askubuntu.com`, `superuser.com`, etc.

Comment: Can you please post some small example that how to deal with this

Comment: I haven't done this. But lemme give a small **demo only** example.